# Angular 5 HttpParams not being set

Tags: angular, http-parameters

I have thins very simple function:

```
createParams(paramsArray, withToken: boolean): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    params.set('access_token', JSON.stringify(currentUser.token));
    return params;
}
```

When i debug this the params variable does not contain any keys nor values:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
let Params = new HttpParams();
Params = Params.append('access_token', JSON.stringify(currentUser.token));
```

OR

```
let params = new HttpParams().set('access_token', JSON.stringify(currentUser.token));
```

> `HttpParams` is intended to be immutable. The `set` and `append`
>   methods don't modify the existing instance. Instead they return new
>   instances.

Comment: Well that's confusing. Thank you!

Comment: seriously ?! who thought this makes sense!